# Meteor Invert Boolean Helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

This may seem like a simple question, but it is one that I have struggled to find documentation for.

I have a spacebars helper that returns values from a collection, in a cursor of objects for use in an `{{#each}}` block. These objects have a boolean property that I use to check/uncheck a checkbox.

However, the boolean values in the database need to be inverted for use in the checkbox. If a record in the collection has the boolean property evaluating to "false," I need it to be "true" in usage.

```
{{#each records}}
{{name}}: <input type="checkbox" checked="{{!checked}}">
{{/each}}
```

The issue here is that `{{!` signals a spacebars comment, rather than converting "false" to "true."
In this snippet, `{{!checked}}` is considered a comment rather than a helper.

Theoretically, I could run a `forEach()` loop in the helper logic and invert the boolean values for each object. However, I feel like there must be a better way for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make yourself a `not` global helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('not',(param)=>{
  return !param;
});
```

Then in any template use `{{not checked}}`